# Delphi: TList Creation, memory error

Tags: delphi, tlist

I tried to create 3 TList but, when i'm creating them i got error.

```
unit ipname;

interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  IpNameData = class
  private
    ips : TList<String>;
    ports : TList<integer>;
    names : TList<String>;
  public
    procedure Add(ip:string; port:integer; name:string);
    procedure Del(ip:string; port:integer; name:string);
    procedure Clear();
    function GetName(i:integer):string;
    function GetIp(i:integer):string;
    function GetPort(i:integer):integer;
    function GetSize(i:integer):integer;


  published
    constructor Create;
  end;
implementation

constructor IpNameData.Create;
begin
  ips := TList<String>.Create();
  ports := TList<integer>.Create();
  names := TList<String>.Create();
end;
...
```

So the problem happen when program reach `ips := TList<String>.Create();`, and i get:

```
First chance exception at $008BACCF. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x008baccf: read of address 0x00000074'. Process Server.exe (5824)
```

I can not figure out what am i doing wrong :\

**EDIT**

Well its a little bit messy for me...

But i have 3 files, ipname is upper, second one is a DataModule called ServerData

```
unit ServerData;

interface

uses
   System.SysUtils, System.Classes, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
    IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, IdContext,FMX.Dialogs, ipname;
type
  TDataModule2 = class(TDataModule)
    TCPServer: TIdTCPServer;
    procedure TCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure TCPServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
  private
    { Private declarations }
     procedure CMDToDo(cmd,ip:string; p:integer);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    Logs:TStrings;
    IPs:TStrings;
    Data : IpNameData;
    procedure SendMSG(IP,msg : string; port : integer);
  end;

var
  DataModule2: TDataModule2;
```

And the last one is the ServerGUI

```
unit ServerGUI;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Layouts,
  FMX.Memo, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Edit, FMX.ListBox;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Options: TGroupBox;
    Power: TSwitch;
    PortField: TEdit;
    Port_label: TLabel;
    Power_label: TLabel;
    LogM: TMemo;
    Logs: TGroupBox;
    IPBox: TListBox;
    IPBox_label: TLabel;
    LogM_label: TLabel;
    procedure PowerSwitch(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses ServerData;
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ServerData.DataModule2.Data.Create;
end;
```

I dont really know where should i call the constructor so i called when form is created...

Comment: Does Create really get called with ()? I didnt code Delphi for years now, but i think to remember that you just call TList<String>.Create; without ().

Comment: Please show the code where you call the IpNameData constructor.

Comment: @Nidhoegger It doesn't matter. The `()` can be included, or omitted.

Comment: Your edit to the question proves that my guess was correct. Your code in the question that fails to create the object correctly is identical to the code in my answer.

Comment: As for how to create `Data`, you are creating it in the wrong place. You need an overridden constructor and destructor in your data module that deals with the lifetime of `Data`. You should not be doing that from the outside.

Comment: You are right @DavidHeffernan , i made Constructor and Desctuctor, and when i call them the 3 list is genereted... but after that they gone, i think its some range problem, so where should i call TDataModule2.Create constructor? :\

Comment: If you use a constructor/destructor you need to override the constructor/destructor in the base class. Your code already creates the data module. Likely with a call to `Application.CreateForm` in the .dpr file. Alternative is to use data module's `OnCreate` and `OnDestroy` events. However, I would like to ask you to return to the original question if possible. Can we please wrap that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the question is fine. The code that is wrong is that which calls the constructor. I am prepared to bet that it reads:

```
var
  Data: IpNameData;
....
Data.Create;
```

where it should read:

```
Data := IpNameData.Create;
```

Comment: Even though its not an error in this case, I would call `Inherited` in the `IpNameData` constructor just to avoid confusion.

Comment: @LURD I agree. And override `Destroy` and destroy the three lists.

Answer (score 0):

As per David's reply + comments, you should replace

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ServerData.DataModule2.Data.Create;
end;
```

with

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ServerData.DataModule2.Data:=IpNameData.Create;
end;
```

and update

```
IpNameData = class
  private
    ips : TList<String>;
    ports : TList<integer>;
    names : TList<String>;
```

to

```
IpNameData = class
  private
    ips : TList<String>;
    ports : TList<integer>;
    names : TList<String>;
    destructor Destroy; override;
```

and add

```
destructor IpNameData.Destroy;
begin
  ips.Free;
  ports.Free;
  Name.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

and change

```
constructor IpNameData.Create;
begin
  ips := TList<String>.Create();
  ports := TList<integer>.Create();
  names := TList<String>.Create();
end;
```

to

```
constructor IpNameData.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  ips := TList<String>.Create();
  ports := TList<integer>.Create();
  names := TList<String>.Create();
end;
```

Feel free to give David the "Checkmark" for reply - I have merely specified his reply in detail.

Comment: `Data` should be created and destroyed by the data module